# google cloud build executing `kubectl get` cannot recognize output format json

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, google-cloud-build

In cloud build logs

```
"Running the following command: kubectl [get httproutes.gateway.networking.k8s.io --field-selector=metadata.name=test-name-http-route --output=json | jq -r '.spec.rules[]?.backendRefs[]? | select(.name == "test-name-service")']"
}
```

```
error: unable to match a printer suitable for the output format "json | jq -r '.spec.rules[]?.backendRefs[]? | select(.name == \"test-name-service\")'", allowed formats are: custom-columns,custom-columns-file,go-template,go-template-file,json,jsonpath,jsonpath-as-json,jsonpath-file,name,template,templatefile,wide,yaml
```

Is it because `jq` is not installed in cloud build?

I was able to run that command in `Google Cloud Shell` directly with no errors:

```
kubectl get httproutes.gateway.networking.k8s.io --field-selector=metadata.name=test-name-http-route --output=json | jq -r '.spec.rules[]?.backendRefs[]? | select(.name == "test-name-service")'
```

Comment: Can you share your Cloud Build step?

Comment: hmm not really, it is an internal project. I am pretty sure it's either jq is not installed or the whitespaces in the command between arguments and flags cannot be recognized by cloud build...Because I replaced the command with jsonpath format, it works great. It just doesn't work with jq for some reason.

Comment: Have a look at this github thread [Add jq builder](https://github.com/bluk/gcp-cloud-builders/commit/f31842641ba1c3a21bf29e8d2d66a55c657d3415)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out `jq` was not installed in the image I was using to execute the command.

Comment: how did you managed to solved this problem